# pgfPlots color plots

Tags: pgfplots

So I would like to present data using a color plot subdivided into squares. For a large data set, it is easy to use a 3D plot with `surf`, however when there is not so much information, this does not work so nicely.

Take for example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3 [surf]
        coordinates {
            (0, 0, 1) (1, 0, 9) (2, 0, 3)

            (0, 1, 4) (1, 1, 5) (2, 1, 6)

            (0, 2, 7) (1, 2, 2) (2, 2, 9)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Naive approach]

I have 9 data points, and 4 squares are displayed which reduces greatly the amount of data displayed.

An alternative I thought of was to use square marks

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, enlargelimits=.3]
    \addplot3 [scatter, mark=square*, mark size=24pt]
        coordinates {
            (0, 0, 1) (1, 0, 9) (2, 0, 3)

            (0, 1, 4) (1, 1, 5) (2, 1, 6)

            (0, 2, 7) (1, 2, 2) (2, 2, 9)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Using marks]

but the result is less than pleasing, and would require a lot of mucking around with the size of the marks.

The only "alternative" is to use interpolation so that at the vertices the correct color is displayed

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp]
        coordinates {
            (0, 0, 1) (1, 0, 9) (2, 0, 3)

            (0, 1, 4) (1, 1, 5) (2, 1, 6)

            (0, 2, 7) (1, 2, 2) (2, 2, 9)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, patch type=bilinear]
        coordinates {
            (0, 0, 1) (1, 0, 9) (2, 0, 3)

            (0, 1, 4) (1, 1, 5) (2, 1, 6)

            (0, 2, 7) (1, 2, 2) (2, 2, 9)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Interpolation]

But without the correct interpolation, looks ugly. Besides, it doesn't exactly fix the problem of displaying only 9 data points.

So for small data sets, is there a way of plotting exactly the same number of squares as required?

Comment: Well, I tried to search tex.sx for a solution to this issue, though I did not see that one. Indeed, it is a duplicate, and using `flat corner` is a solution, though not exactly ideal as it gives the impression that the data points are actually between the vertices. It is still significantly better though.

I gave it more thought, and is it possible to define your own marker so that the width is exactly half of the distance separating vertices, and have the vertical/horizontal scalings independent? That would fix the issue.

Also, should I post this suggestion in the duplicate?

Comment: Well, you can say `mark size=1` (without unit), provided that `\pgfplotsset{compat=<version>}` is high enough (`1.8` will do). In that case, pgfplots will take one axis unit. I believe there was some solution (probably of @Jake) which relied on this feature. And: yes, I suppose flagging this as dupe is a good idea - you can post work-arounds or answers on the original one.

Comment: Just one last thing regarding your last reply, but using `mark size=1` does not seem to work. I am using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}`, so I don't know what is the issue. Also, [the documentation](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) does not seem to show `mark size=1` as scaling to one unit.

Also, this would not allow x and y scaling to be specified individually? Unless perhaps the cube marker is used?

Comment: @Josh: You might want to take a look at [matlab2tikz imagesc TikZ/pgfplots equivalent](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124276/matlab2tikz-imagesc-tikz-pgfplots-equivalent/124283#124283) (I believe that's the question Christian had in mind).

Comment: @Josh my bad: sorry, the `mark size=1` hint was wrong; I must have mistaken it for `bar width` (which accepts axis units). Please excuse me. And yes, I meant the link posted by Jake, perhaps it helps you.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed.

The only little issue I've been having now is that `mark=square*` has to be square (obviously). `mark=cube*` however seems to allow custom x/y sizes and I tried adapting Jake's code so that the width and height of the graph aren't affected, but without success. For some reason settings `cube/size x' does not do anything. I also cannot comment on Jake's answer to suggest this possibility (it requires 50 reputations...)