# Generate a Hinton diagram using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In one of my previous [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124276/matlab2tikz-imagesc-tikz-pgfplots-equivalent), the magnificent [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake) helped me generate a heatmap that looks identical to using imagesc on a 2D matrix within MATLAB.

The results look great, but now I'm looking to modify its behaviour in order to create a Hinton diagram. A Hinton diagram is a cool way of visualising the magnitudes and directions of the weights in a neural network. Instead of using a colourmap to decide the colour of each "pixel" (e.g., black is -1, white is 1 and anything in between is a scale of grey), it uses colours x and y for negative and positive values respectively, and the magnitude is visualised by the size of the square marker. Below is an example output from a [Python interpretation](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/HintonDiagrams) (the code might inspire someone).

[image]

Ideally, it would be possible to tuck all this away in a style.

As a bonus, it'd be great to have the ability to read a file that stores the data in a matrix's natural representation:

```
 2.76658    -0.07990     0.10551    -2.94131     0.00840     0.23832    -2.56759     0.04593
-0.21476     2.37350    -2.30670     0.11634    -2.36124     2.62034    -0.32261     2.36860
 0.01118    -2.42926     2.42470     0.08698     2.45065    -2.39544    -0.16931    -2.32933
-3.04568    -0.15376     0.03051     2.74830    -0.07237     0.02359     2.96758     0.05812
-0.12791    -2.50370     2.63524     0.15000     2.26310    -2.39198    -0.05032    -2.41050
-0.07663     2.40350    -2.45346    -0.00479    -2.62160     2.29896    -0.11746     2.49031
-2.90385    -0.11742    -0.15037     2.88956     0.01517    -0.06700     2.96463    -0.10442
-0.17761     2.01661    -2.23660    -0.07113    -2.39688     2.19306     0.07902     2.37361
```

Or, if that's not feasible, in a traditional x-y-data format like this:

```
0 0 2.766580
1 0 -0.079900
2 0 0.105510
3 0 -2.941310
4 0 0.008400
5 0 0.238320
6 0 -2.567590
7 0 0.045930
0 1 -0.214760
1 1 2.373500
2 1 -2.306700
3 1 0.116340
4 1 -2.361240
5 1 2.620340
6 1 -0.322610
7 1 2.368600
0 2 0.011180
1 2 -2.429260
2 2 2.424700
3 2 0.086980
4 2 2.450650
5 2 -2.395440
6 2 -0.169310
7 2 -2.329330
0 3 -3.045680
1 3 -0.153760
2 3 0.030510
3 3 2.748300
4 3 -0.072370
5 3 0.023590
6 3 2.967580
7 3 0.058120
0 4 -0.127910
1 4 -2.503700
2 4 2.635240
3 4 0.150000
4 4 2.263100
5 4 -2.391980
6 4 -0.050320
7 4 -2.410500
0 5 -0.076630
1 5 2.403500
2 5 -2.453460
3 5 -0.004790
4 5 -2.621600
5 5 2.298960
6 5 -0.117460
7 5 2.490310
0 6 -2.903850
1 6 -0.117420
2 6 -0.150370
3 6 2.889560
4 6 0.015170
5 6 -0.067000
6 6 2.964630
7 6 -0.104420
0 7 -0.177610
1 7 2.016610
2 7 -2.236600
3 7 -0.071130
4 7 -2.396880
5 7 2.193060
6 7 0.079020
7 7 2.373610
```

You can generate the second data format from the first using a Python script like this:

```py
import numpy as np
rawdata = np.loadtxt('data.dat')
coords = np.meshgrid(np.arange(np.shape(rawdata)[0]),
                     np.arange(np.shape(rawdata)[1]))
data = np.vstack([coords[0].flatten(), coords[1].flatten(), rawdata.flatten()]).T
np.savetxt('weights-example.dat', data, fmt="%i %i %f")
```

This is probably a bit too much to ask of the `TikZ`/`pgfplots` gurus as I have not really put any effort into solving this, but, alas, I cannot even fully understand how Jake's code works. If anyone's willing to help, I guess [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124283/32206) to my previous question would be the place to start.

Comment: I know nothing. But two questions come to my mind: (1) should the biggest square possible be the one with the  biggest absolute value? In that case it wouldn't be easier if the numbers provided where between -1 and 1?; (2) does the magnitude represent the area of the square or the length of the sides? I suppose the answer is the first one.

Comment: @Manuel (1) Yes, the biggest square should be the one with the biggest absolute value. So all squares have the same area, but only the maximum magnitude uses the whole area. It would help if the data were normalised in the range [-1 1], but I'd imagine that `pgfplots` provides the capability to normalise the data on the go. (2) I think it represents the area of the square. I could be wrong though! That' why I linked to the Python code! `:-)`

Comment: You can use the `pgf` backend of `matplotlib` and export the diagram to pgf code, which you can then `\input` into your latex document. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @Psirus I would be interested in that answer and I would definitely up-vote it (as would many others I believe), but I'd prefer a solution that's not as involved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way to do this in PGFPlots. I used the `x,y,value` data instead of the matrix, because that's much easier to process using PGFPlots.

I've defined a `fenton` style which can be added to the `axis` options. With your test file and the following code...

```
\begin{axis}[fenton]
\addplot table [meta index=2] {weights-example.dat};
\end{axis}
```

... you'll get

[image]

The styles for the positive and negative values can be set using `fenton/positive style={...}` and `fenton/negative style={...}`.

---

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    fenton/positive/.style={fill=white, draw=none},
    fenton/positive style/.style={/pgfplots/fenton/positive/.append style={#1}},
    fenton/negative/.style={fill=black, draw=none},
    fenton/negative style/.style={/pgfplots/fenton/negative/.append style={#1}},
    fenton/.style={
        axis background/.style={fill=gray},
        only marks, no markers,
        scatter,
        axis equal image,
        axis on top,
        major tick length=0pt,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
        enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
        point meta=explicit,
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\normalisedsize{
                sqrt(
                    abs(
                        \pgfplotspointmeta / max(
                            abs(\pgfplots@metamin),
                            abs(\pgfplots@metamax)
                        )
                    )
                )
            }
            \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{+}{
                \pgfplotsset{fenton/current value/.style=/pgfplots/fenton/positive}
            }{
                \pgfplotsset{fenton/current value/.style=/pgfplots/fenton/negative}
            }
            \path [/pgfplots/fenton/current value] ([scale=\normalisedsize]axis direction cs:-0.5,-0.5) rectangle ([scale=\normalisedsize]axis direction cs:0.5,0.5);   
        },
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={}
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[fenton]
\addplot table [meta index=2] {weights-example.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic work like usual, Jake! Thanks a ton! You make me love `TikZ` and `pgfplots` more by the day.

Comment: @sudosensei: Thanks for the compliments! `=)` Glad it helps

Answer (score 10):

I think this does it. Could have done it in pure `tex` but today I am lazy, and so this requires `lualatex`. The file reading method is *not* robust. Also I've used just black or white colors (no in between shading).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
2.76658    -0.07990     0.10551    -2.94131     0.00840     0.23832    -2.56759     0.04593
-0.21476     2.37350    -2.30670     0.11634    -2.36124     2.62034    -0.32261     2.36860
 0.01118    -2.42926     2.42470     0.08698     2.45065    -2.39544    -0.16931    -2.32933
-3.04568    -0.15376     0.03051     2.74830    -0.07237     0.02359     2.96758     0.05812
-0.12791    -2.50370     2.63524     0.15000     2.26310    -2.39198    -0.05032    -2.41050
-0.07663     2.40350    -2.45346    -0.00479    -2.62160     2.29896    -0.11746     2.49031
-2.90385    -0.11742    -0.15037     2.88956     0.01517    -0.06700     2.96463    -0.10442
-0.17761     2.01661    -2.23660    -0.07113    -2.39688     2.19306     0.07902     2.37361
\end{filecontents*}

{\catcode`\%=11\gdef\pc{%}}
\begin{document}
\directlua{%
Matrix = {}
Matrix.__index = Matrix

function Matrix.new()
  local obj = {nrow=0, ncol=0, max=-math.huge, min=math.huge, data={}}
  setmetatable(obj, Matrix)
  return obj
end
function Matrix.fromFile(f)
  local obj, file, line, row, v, c
  obj = Matrix.new()
  file = io.open(f)
  if file then
     for line in file:lines() do
       row = {}
       c = 0
       for v in string.gmatch(line, "\pc S+") do
          v = tonumber(v)
          if v > obj.max then obj.max = v end
          if v < obj.min then obj.min = v end
          table.insert(row, v)
          c = c + 1
       end
       table.insert(obj.data, row)
       obj.nrow = obj.nrow + 1
       if c > obj.ncol then
          obj.ncol = obj.ncol + 1
       end
     end
  end
  return obj
end

function Matrix:get(i, j)
  if self.data[i][j] then
    return self.data[i][j]
  else
    return 0
  end
end  

function Matrix:set(i, j, v)
  if self.data[i] == nil then
    table.insert(self.data, i, {})
  end
  table.insert(self.data[i], j, v)
  if i > self.nrow then self.nrow = i end
  if j > self.ncol then self.ncol = j end
end

function Matrix:normalize()
  local i, j, v
  for i = 1,self.ncol do
    for j = 1,self.nrow do
      self.data[i][j] = 2*(self.data[i][j] - self.min) / (self.max - self.min) - 1
    end
  end
  self.max = 1
  self.min = -1
end
}

\def\getlua#1{\directlua{tex.print("" .. #1)}}

\directlua{
  M = Matrix.fromFile("data.dat")
  M:normalize()
}
\newcommand\hinton[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\fill [black!15] (0,0) rectangle ++(\getlua{#2.ncol}+1, \getlua{#2.nrow}+1);
\foreach \i in {1,...,\getlua{#2.ncol}}{
  \foreach \j [evaluate={\v=\getlua{#2:get(\i, \j)}; \c=(\v<0 ? 100 : 0); \s=\v; }] in {1,...,\getlua{#2.nrow}}{
    \fill [black!\c!white] (\i, \j) ++(-\s/2,-\s/2) rectangle ++(\s,\s);
  }}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\hinton{M}

\directlua{%
N = Matrix.new()
local i, j
for i = 1,25 do
  for j = 1,25 do
    N:set(i, j, math.random()*2-1)
  end
end
}

\hinton[x=5pt, y=5pt]{N}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a lovely answer. But since the original question was about doing this with `pgfplots` (personal preference), I have to accept Jake's answer. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the comments, you can export the `matplotlib` figure to `pgf` code and in turn compile this with latex.
I added a small bit of code to generate some fake data, and replaced the `P.show()` with `P.savefig('hinton_code.pgf')` to write the diagram to the file:

```
import numpy as N
import pylab as P

def _blob(x,y,area,colour):
    hs = N.sqrt(area) / 2
    xcorners = N.array([x - hs, x + hs, x + hs, x - hs])
    ycorners = N.array([y - hs, y - hs, y + hs, y + hs])
    P.fill(xcorners, ycorners, colour, edgecolor=colour)

def hinton(W, maxWeight=None):
    reenable = False
    if P.isinteractive():
        P.ioff()
    P.clf()
    height, width = W.shape
    if not maxWeight:
        maxWeight = 2**N.ceil(N.log(N.max(N.abs(W)))/N.log(2))
    P.fill(N.array([0,width,width,0]),N.array([0,0,height,height]), 'gray')
    P.axis('off')
    P.axis('equal')
    for x in xrange(width):
        for y in xrange(height):
            _x = x+1
            _y = y+1
            w = W[y,x]
            if w > 0:
                _blob(_x - 0.5, height - _y + 0.5, min(1,w/maxWeight),'white')
            elif w < 0:
                _blob(_x - 0.5, height - _y + 0.5, min(1,-w/maxWeight), 'k')
    if reenable:
        P.ion()
    P.savefig('hinton_code.pgf')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    W = N.random.rand(15, 15) - 0.5*N.ones((15,15))
    hinton(W)
```

Creating a document would then be as simple as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\input{hinton_code.pgf}
\end{document}
```

Also, I expect reading in the data file to be much easier in Python than it would be in TeX.

Comment: Thanks! This answer does exactly what was asked, except the `pgfplots` part. Since there's a `pgfplots` solution, I can't mark this as the accepted answer though.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple solution using only TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds}
\def\mymatrix{%
  {2.76658, -0.07990, 0.10551, -2.94131, 0.00840, 0.23832, -2.56759, 0.04593},
  {-0.21476, 2.37350, -2.30670, 0.11634, -2.36124, 2.62034, -0.32261, 2.36860},
  {0.01118, -2.42926, 2.42470, 0.08698, 2.45065, -2.39544, -0.16931, -2.32933},
  {-3.04568, -0.15376, 0.03051, 2.74830, -0.07237, 0.02359, 2.96758, 0.05812},
  {-0.12791, -2.50370, 2.63524, 0.15000, 2.26310, -2.39198, -0.05032, -2.41050},
  {-0.07663, 2.40350, -2.45346, -0.00479, -2.62160, 2.29896, -0.11746, 2.49031},
  {-2.90385, -0.11742, -0.15037, 2.88956, 0.01517, -0.06700, 2.96463, -0.10442},
  {-0.17761, 2.01661, -2.23660, -0.07113, -2.39688, 2.19306, 0.07902, 2.37361}%
}
\def\max{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \line [count=\y] in \mymatrix {
     \foreach \val [count=\x] in \line {
       \pgfmathsetmacro\col{(\val>=0)?"orange":"lime"}
       \pgfmathsetmacro\len{sqrt(abs(\val)/\max)/2}
       \fill[fill=\col] (\x,-\y) +(\len cm,\len cm) rectangle +(-\len cm,-\len cm);
     }
   }
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \node[fill=gray,fit=(current bounding box),inner sep=1mm,draw]{};
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 It is very easy to implement this algorithm with PSTricks.

Comment: +1! Nice one. I didn't think that a `TikZ`-only solution would be this simple and elegant.