# imagesc TikZ/pgfplots equivalent, axes problems

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

following [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124276/matlab2tikz-imagesc-tikz-pgfplots-equivalent/), i tried to reproduce a MATLAB imagesc with tikz. The graph should look like this:
[image]
However, in constrast to the aforementioned link, my graph should have 19 rows and 192 columns and I have problems defining the matrix row, cols.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
matrix plot/.style={
      axis on top,
      clip marker paths=true,
      scale only axis,
      height=\matrixrows/\matrixcols*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width},
    enlarge x limits={rel=0.5/\matrixcols},
    enlarge y limits={rel=0.5/\matrixrows},
           scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color, fill=mapped color},
          scatter,
    point meta=explicit,
    mark=square*,
    cycle list={
        mark size=0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}/\matrixcols
    }
},
 matrix rows/.store in=\matrixrows,
 matrix rows=19,
 matrix cols/.store in=\matrixcols,
 matrix cols=192}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      % view={0}{180},
       width=5cm, 
        matrix plot,
        colormap/hot,
        colorbar,
    ]  
              \addplot table [ meta=funceval] {data/data1.txt};
\end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please find the data under the link [data1.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/19wzl22tsw1g8d4/AAA4VucAQCys4NmLOTSUpT7za?dl=0)

Could you please help me:

1. reproduce the imagesc plot with the correct dimensions as in the Matlab plot (location 1 should start from top)?
2. derive a colormap similar to the one obtained by matlab?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you could try the viridis colormap. It should be better than the matlab colormap (in my opinion): http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254518/44467

Comment: For the location axis starting from top: try the axis option `y dir = reverse`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I think the main problem is, that you most probably have saved your data in a wrong manner. If you fix that, than you should already have what you want (except the `colormap`). But please note, that you can achieve this in a much simpler manner using `matrix plot`. Please have a look at [*my* answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286925/95441) in the link to the question you provided.

Comment: To the `colormap`: Either you use the `viridis` colormap as suggested by [Faekynn](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354613/comment872305_354613) which in the meantime is already incorporated into PGFPlots, so it does not have to be defined any more (as you can also see in ["*my*" answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286925/95441) or you can define the `parula` (Matlab) `colormap` which is also explained in [Faekynn's link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354613/comment872305_354613) a bit more up by [Jake](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228241/95441).

Comment: Did the comments help you to solve the problem or do you need further assistance?